# Entity Framework LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How do I find which clubs have the most players in query. So the query would contain all the clubs that have the most players. For example if first club has 3 players, second club has 5 players and third club also has 5 players then there would be second and third club in the query. And i need to return list of the clubs.

```
public List<Club> ClubWithMostPlayers()
{
     using (var context = new dataContext())
     {
          var query = ?????

          return query.ToList();
     }
}
```

These are classes that i use

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public int yearOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PlayerClub> playerClub { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string stadium { get; set; }
    public int yearOfConstruction { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PlayerClub> playerClub { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerClub
{
    public int PlayerClubId { get; set; }

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    public virtual Player player { get; set; }
    public virtual Club club { get; set; }

    public int from { get; set; }
    public int to { get; set; }
    public int appearances { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to do it in SQL, but not in LINQ

Thank you for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about dividing your query into two parts.

```
// get number of maximum number of players in one club
var count = context.Clubs.Select(c => c.playerClub.Count()).Max();

// get clubs with specific number of players
var query = context.Clubs
    .Where(c => c.playerClub.Count() == count);
```

Comment: Thank you that is a very nice solution and not much code :)